# SpringJdbcTemplate: SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type 1111 while executing function with return value as JavaObject

Tags: java-7

I am using Spring `jdbcTemplate` with oracle 11g in my project. I have faced problem in executing function with return value as java type. Please kindly help me for this issue.

Here I have added the outline of structure:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FUNC_DETAILS(
    P_FIRST         NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
    P_SECOND       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'N')
  RETURN JAVA_OBJ_TYPE
AS



create or replace TYPE JAVA_OBJ_TYPE
AS
  OBJECT
  (
    dash_board ANOTHER_JAVA_OBJ,
    card_dtls ANOTHER2_JAVA_OBJ,
    address_dtls ANOTHER3_JAVA_OBJ
  )

create or replace TYPE ANOTHER_JAVA_OBJ
AS
  OBJECT
  (
    FIRST_NUMBER         VARCHAR2(50),
    SECOND_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50),
  )

create or replace TYPE ANOTHER2_JAVA_OBJ
AS
  OBJECT
  (
    FIRST_NUMBER         VARCHAR2(50),
    SECOND_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50),
  )
create or replace TYPE ANOTHER3_JAVA_OBJ
AS
  OBJECT
  (
    FIRST_NUMBER         VARCHAR2(50),
    SECOND_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50),
  )



In java code:
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                    .withCatalogName(packageName) // package name
                    .withFunctionName(functionName);
                return simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(JavaObj.class, in)
```

It throws this error:

```
SpringJdbcTemplate: SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type 1111 while executing function with return value as JavaObject
```